# How to cluster an image using DBSCAN and get the output through image?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

How to cluster in according to color values , for e.g clustering range of road colour values into one and giving the output in the same.

I implemented one but it clustered everything into one colour. I think i clustered in according to pixels not in according to colour values, and as everything is already densed, it just gave an output of one colour. But still I dont think i did the right way. 
If the entire code is provided from scratch, it would be very much clear.Thankyou

Comment: Did you check that you have multiple clusters? It's fairly easy to get only one cluster in DBSCAN by setting eps too small (everything noise) or too large (everything the same cluster)...

Comment: How to apply DBSCAN just like in this  post and output the image as shown- [link](https://dzone.com/articles/cluster-image-with-k-means)

Comment: The same way as with KMeans. So write code, and choose parameters right. How did you choose epsilon?

Comment: @Anony-Mousseepsilon as 1..But how to plot the figure ? what should i put in place of cluster_centers[cluster_labels] in plt.imshow(cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(x, y, z))..I mean showing the clustered pixels on the image as shown in the link rather then making a graph

Comment: Why do you think 1 is a good value? For plotting, just assign random colors to each cluster (the code you linked clearly did not work as intended...)

Comment: k-means is used to do color quantization of images. This is not really a clustering application, but more a use of k-means to discretize the color space into k regions. DBSCAN is typically not used for this application since tuning the parameters will be tricky and needs to be done for each image individually. Also chaining will be an issue.